# php - usage nested loops and case

Tags: php, loops, nested, switch-statement, case

First of all - excuse me if my rudimentary PHP skills has pushed me into asking something which might be basic or trivial, but I have searched the site without results (maybe because i do not know the technical term for such a thing ..)

I have a nested for each loop , but based on simple variables `($e)` , I would need to either use the whole loop (2 nested parts) OR use only one (the inner).

```
   $a = array(); //some array ...
   $c = array(); //some other array ...
   $e = 'yes' // or 'no'

    if ($a) {
                foreach ($a as $b) {

                    $a_1[] = 'something_quite_long'; //that would  affects $c if used

                        foreach ( $c as $d ) {

                        //do_something_very long...

                        }
                }
            }
```

so right now I have resolved this by using `switch $e:` and `case`  - but that has moer than duplicated the length of my code , because what I did was made one case as the whole nested loop, and the other case - the only inner loop (which is loooong..)
I am sure there is some ninja-technique to use in such a case without simply copying and pasting the whole code in a "`case`" - but I have no idea how .

Anyone ?

NOTE : I know I could presumably use an external function, but the problem is that in the very long second (inner) loop - there are one or two minor cases where the verbal output (HTML) would change slightly ..

**Edit I** - Due to unclarity from comments , here is the code (with much reduced loops - the actual loop is much longer) - although not relevant to the question. the code is wordpress related..

```
function o99_get_image_size_links($title='',$single,$recieved_id) {

    /* If not viewing an image attachment page, return. */


    /* Set up an empty array for the links. */
    $links = array();

    /* Get the intermediate image sizes and add the full size to the array. */
    $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

    $sizes[] = 'full';

    global $post;

    switch ($single) {

    case 'FALSE':

    // this will do to all images attached to a post ..
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment','post_mime_type' => $mime, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID', 'posts_per_page'=>$limit) );

    /* Loop through each of the image sizes. */

        if ($attachments) {

            foreach ($attachments as $att) { 


                $links[] = '<br>' . get_the_title($att->ID) .' || '. basename ( get_attached_file( $att->ID ) ).' || '. $att->post_name .' || ' /*. wp_get_attachment_image( $att->ID, 'tooltip' ).' || ' .'<br/>'*/  ; // k99 add

                if ($title) {
                    $links[] = '<br><b>' . $title . '</b></br>';
                    }

                    foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {

                        /* Get the image source, width, height, and whether it's intermediate. */

                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att->ID, $size );

                        /* Add the link to the array if there's an image and if $is_intermediate (4th array value) is true or full size. */

                        if ( !empty( $image ) && ( true == $image[3] || 'full' == $size ) )

                            $links[] = "</br><a class='image-size-link_{$image[1]}&times;{$image[2]}' href='{$image[0]}'>{$image[1]} &times; {$image[2]}</a>";
                    }
            }
        }

break;

//case for single image ..

case 'TRUE':

                $links[] = '<br>' . get_the_title($recieved_id) .' || '. basename ( get_attached_file( $recieved_id ) ).' || '. $att->post_name .' || ' /*. wp_get_attachment_image( $att->ID, 'tooltip' ).' || ' .'<br/>'*/  ; // k99 add

                if ($title) {
                    $links[] = '<br><b>' . $title . '</b></br>';
                    }

                    foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {

                        /* Get the image source, width, height, and whether it's intermediate. */

                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $recieved_id, $size );

                        /* Add the link to the array if there's an image and if $is_intermediate (4th array value) is true or full size. */

                        if ( !empty( $image ) && ( true == $image[3] || 'full' == $size ) )

                            $links[] = "</br><a class='image-size-link_{$image[1]}&times;{$image[2]}' href='{$image[0]}'>{$image[1]} &times; {$image[2]}</a>";
                    }
break;
}
    /* Join the links in a string and return. */


    return join( '<span class="sep"> /</span> ', $links );

}
```

Comment: Can't see any `switch` statement in your code ?? and it not clear from your code what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Baba nop - because the switch would only duplicate the loop . this is why I only verbaly wrote it (the whole code is an example only ). I can Add it if necessary ..

Comment: your not going to be able to use `$c as $d` when you have defined $d earlier as some sort of 'yes/no' flag. your flag will be overwritten.

Comment: @SamuelCook - sorry, my bad, fixed it now ..

Comment: Please add expected Input and output .. this would make it clear what you want to achive

Comment: Where does `$a_1` come to play and what do you mean by `/that would  affects $c if used`

Comment: @Baba - I am sorry, what is $a_1 ? you mean the first array object ?

Comment: @Obmerk Kronen looking at your updated code one moment

Comment: I see what you mean now .. it can be improved .. also see a lot of bad practice in your code

Comment: @Baba - I am sorry, I am a total begginer - I know my code is bad - hence the " rudimentary PHP skills " in OP . Please feel free to note and comment any bad practice ... :-)

Comment: Some receivables are not even defined such as `$mime` and `$limit` ??

Comment: @Baba - As I wrote before - this is the SHORT version of the function. the actual one is maybe 700 lines ... I have posted only the relevant parts for the question. Both `$mime` and `$limit` are not relevant to the direct question, and in any case, have no actual influence because the function will work also with NULL (with is the wp defaults..)

Comment: @Obmerk Kronen see below code for example .. and tell me if that is what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have so many issues with your code .. but this is to give you an idea how to minimized your code

Issues

- Use Of global `global $post;`
- `$mime` and `$limit` not declared
- `basename ( get_attached_file( $recieved_id ) ).' || '. $att->post_name .' || '` outside the loop that defines `foreach ($attachments as $att)`
- `$recieved_id` var argument and `$post->ID` via post ????
- etc

There is no way your script can work with this error .. so i'll just give you a guide on how to improve your function

```
function k99_get_image_size_links($title = '', $single ,  $recieved_id , $mime =null , $limit = null) {
    $links = array();
    $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    $sizes[] = 'full';
    $pad = function ($ID) use(&$links,$sizes,$title) {
        $links[] = '<br>' . get_the_title($ID) . ' || ' . basename(get_attached_file($ID)) . ' || ' . $title  . ' || ' ;
        empty($title) OR $links[] = sprintf('<br><b>%s</b></br>',$title);
        foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($ID, $size);
            if (! empty($image) && (true == $image[3] || 'full' == $size))
                $links[] = sprintf('</br><a class="image-size-link_%s&times;%s" href="%s">%1$s &times; %2$s</a>',$image[1],$image[2],$image[0]);
        }
    };

    if ($single === true) {
        $pad($recieved_id);
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children(array('post_parent' => $recieved_id,'post_status' => 'inherit','post_type' => 'attachment',
                                          'post_mime_type' => $mime,'order' => 'ASC','orderby' => 'menu_order ID','posts_per_page' => $limit));
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $att ) {
                $pad($att->ID);
            }
        }
    }
    return join('<span class="sep"> /</span> ', $links);
}
```

***Please Not the above code is not tested just to show you how you can use `Closure` remove duplication in your code***

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will look and post if I have questions . as for the issues : 1 - the global $post is in order to have the wp $post object available. (wrong??) 2 - Both `$mime` and `$limit` have no actual influence because the function will work also with NULL (with is the wp defaults..) - and are totally irrelevant. 3- this is the major change that caused me to ask the question somehow .. 4- `$recieved_id` is for single image ,`$post->ID` is automatic (loops ALL).(it is not `$POST`). right now the function DOES work.my problem was code optimization and not malfunction. I will check yours now

Comment: in that case use [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) like `$pad` above to minimize duplicate codes .. also use `sprintf` to minimize variable usage duplication .....

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was just going to ask you about this `$pad` and `use`- I will read and try implement now . THANKS again for your info time !

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

```
if ($a) {
            foreach ($a as $b) {
```

As `$a` is an array and only an array evaluates true in the `if`, you don't need the `if` at all. `foreach` will do zero iterations on an empty array, so the `if` is superfluous.

```
   $d = 'yes' // or 'no'

   ...
                        foreach ( $c as $d ) {
                                        ^^^
```

You are overwriting the `$d` variable here. That might cause your problem. Let's clean the code an review:

```
$a = array(); //some array ...
$c = array(); //some other array ...
$e = 'yes' // or 'no'

foreach ($a as $b)
{
    $a_1[] = 'something_quite_long'; //that would  affects $c if used
    foreach ($c as $d)
    {
        // do_something_very long...
    }
}
```

If you now give the variables better names, the looping should have become more clear so less places to do errors.

Comment: @harke  - thanks, but I have already fixed it after Baba comment. .

Answer (score 0):

You can break out of a foreach loop with the `break;` command which skips out of the loop and carries on with the next step which in your code is the next iteration of the outer loop. Also you are overwriting $d in each iteration of the inner loop here `foreach ($c as $d)`

Comment: thanks fot the `break` tip - but I do not want to break the loop, i want either to use ALL the loop, or in another case, just it´s INNER part .